# How to get predictions from fit_generator() in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

Is there any way to get the predictions, something like we can get by model.predict(), of validation dataset from model.fit_generator() in Keras?

```
fit_generator(my_generator_train(), 
              samples_per_epoch=100, 
              nb_epoch=200, 
              verbose=1, 
              validation_data=my_generator_valid(), 
              nb_val_samples=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own custom `callback`. Look at [this](http://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback) link.